# For each line "for loop" cant implement in my script

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, replace, line

I'am completely new to Python and I'm struggling currently with an "easy" step for most of you.

My Target is to copy and paste lines from one source file to a target file.
BUT. The Targetfiles should keep their first 12 lines. after the 12 lines it should take ALL lines from the source file. Works great so far. I only have to set the lines for the last part.

So I have to put in a loop thats like " for each line you find replace it in the target file)

```
config_fstab = '# /etc/fstab: static file system information.'
einhaengepunkte_replace = '#Eigene_Einhaengepunkte'

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING02.txt') as input_header_stays:
    with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt','w') as zwischenspeicher:
        zeilen = input_header_stays.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(zeilen):
            if line.startswith(config_fstab):
                zwischenspeicher.write(line)
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 1])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 2])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 3])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 4])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 5])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 6])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 7])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 8])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 9])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 10])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 11])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 12])
input_header_stays.close()
zwischenspeicher.close()

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING.txt') as input_scripting_fstab:
    with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt','a') as zwischenspeicher:
        zeilen = input_scripting_fstab.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(zeilen):
            if line.startswith(einhaengepunkte_replace):
                zwischenspeicher.write(line)
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 1])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 2])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 3])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 4])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 5])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 6])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 7])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 8])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 9])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 10])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 11])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 12])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 13])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 14])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 15])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 16])

input_scripting_fstab.close()
zwischenspeicher.close()
```

That's my code.

I think the tricky part where I need help is this one:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING.txt') as input_scripting_fstab:
    with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt','a') as zwischenspeicher:
        zeilen = input_scripting_fstab.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(zeilen):
            if line.startswith(einhaengepunkte_replace):
                zwischenspeicher.write(line)
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 1])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 2])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 3])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 4])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 5])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 6])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 7])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 8])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 9])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 10])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 11])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 12])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 13])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 14])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 15])
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + 16])
```

The lines are getting more and I can't put lines in by myself. That's where my Python script needs brain.

Comment: You don't need to do `file.close()` because you are already using `with open("...") as file:`. This automatically takes care of closing the file as soon as you unindent.

Comment: Thanks. i removed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need enumerate if you only want to copy after a certain point to the end of the file.

```
einhaengepunkte_replace = '#Eigene_Einhaengepunkte'

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING.txt', 'r') as input_scripting_fstab:
    zeilen = input_scripting_fstab.readlines()

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt', 'a') as zwischenspeicher:
    writing = False
    for line in zeilen:
        # This flag just tells us when to start writing
        if line.startswith(einhaengepunkte_replace):
            writing = True

        if writing:
            zwischenspeicher.write(line)
```

Since you have a pattern you could even throw it into a function.

```
def copy_it(source='', destination='', start_point='', mode='a'):
    with open(source, 'r') as source_file:
        source_lines = source_file.readlines()

    with open(destination, mode) as dest_file:
        writing = False
        for line in source_lines:
            if line.startswith(start_point):
                writing = True

            if writing:
                dest_file.write(line)


copy_it(source=r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING.txt',
        destination=r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt',
        start_point='#Eigene_Einhaengepunkte')

copy_it(source=r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING02.txt',
        destination=r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt',
        start_point='# /etc/fstab: static file system information.',
        mode='w')
```

Comment: `write(line)` not `write(zeilen)` ;)

Comment: this is brilliant. Thank you so much.

Its hard for a beginner to understand everything. But i will learn with your code now line by line. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a loop to write the desired amount of lines.

```
lines_to_copy = 16

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\SCRIPTING.txt', 'r') as input_scripting_fstab:
    zeilen = input_scripting_fstab.readlines()

with open(r'C:\Users\sample\Desktop\ZWISCHENSPEICHER.txt', 'a') as zwischenspeicher:
    for i, line in enumerate(zeilen):
        if line.startswith(einhaengepunkte_replace):
            for n in range(lines_to_copy): # Copy the next 16 lines.
                zwischenspeicher.write(zeilen[i + n]) # <---
```

Comment: Thanks. This would make my script much smaller.
But bhe Problem i have isnt fixed then.

Ill have to set the "number 16". And if my sourcefile grows ill have to edit my script.

Is there a way to "lines_to_copy" fill itself? to read the lines first and then edit the number in your variable?

Comment: Yes we will find a way to make it fill itself. We just need to know, where does the value 16 come from?

Comment: End of file :)
We could search for "\n" i guess

Comment: File is build like that:
'''
Information that has to be removed from source file because target file has its own information in it  Line 1-12

Information from Sourcefile that Targetfile needs.
Line 13 - till end. (Line 13 starts with "#Eigene_Einhaengepunkte")

For now we have Line 13-29. But maybe in a week there is a new entry and then it would be Line 13-30.

after this the file has no other lines
```


Thanks for helping me out man. I appreciate that!

Comment: Then we could use `len(zeilen) - 12` instead of a hardcoded `16`. @Axe319's solution is pretty good because it gets rid of the `enumerate` entirely :)

Comment: Thats right. thanks for your help. Nice community. :)